# JqueryUI autocomplete result list to go with jquery Mobile

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-mobile, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I want to push result list of autocomplete source inside **ul** element of jquery mobile, I suspect open event can help me out here. If any of you have achieved something like this, would be great help to me (new to jquery)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.14/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function () {
    $("#searchText").autocomplete({
        source: '/CRM/SearchResult',
        minLength: 1,
        appendTo: "#searchResultList",
        open: function () {             

        }
    });
});

</script>

<input type="text" name="searchText" id="searchText" />
  <ul data-role="listview" id="searchResultList">

  </ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I achieved the desired output by extracting barebones of jquermobile tags with the help of Firebug (i am not sure if this was good idea, but it is working great for me):

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("#searchTextBox").change(function (e) {
                var searchTerm = $("#searchTextBox").val();
                if (searchTerm.length == 0) {
                    $('ul li').remove();
                }
                else if (searchTerm.length >= 2) {
                    $('ul li').remove();
                    $.getJSON(
                        '/XYZ/SearchResult',
                        { term: searchTerm },
                         function (response) {

                             $.each(response, function (index) {
                                 var entityID = response[index].id;
                                 var displayText = response[index].label;

                                 var listItem = ' <li class="ui-btn ui-btn-icon-right ui-li "><div class="ui-btn-inner ui-li"><div class="ui-btn-text"><a href="/XYC/XDetail/' + entityID + '" target="_self" class="ui-link-inherit">' + displayText + '</a></div><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrow-r"></span></div></li>';

                                 $(listItem).appendTo("#ui-listview");

                             });

                         });
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
}

<div class="ui-input-search">
    <input placeholder="Filter items..." data-type="search" class="ui-input-text ui-body-null"
        id="searchTextBox" width>  
</div>
<p />
<div class="content-primary">
    <ul data-role="listview" class="ui-listview" id="ui-listview">
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can indeed do this. You need to provide `open` with a callback function, and this ill be triggered once the autocomplete menu is opened. Your function should therefore do something as follows. First, get a handle on your unordered list container:

```
var list = $('#searchResultList');
```

... then iterate your search results (`$.each()` or similar should do). For each result value, `append` a list item to your `ul`:

```
list.append('<li>' + YOUR_RESULT_VALUE + '</li>');
```

... and then finally you will need to refresh the list so that jQM updates the UI properly:

```
list.listview('refresh');
```

Comment: Thanks Ben. I tried that but jquery mobile does not work the way I want it, it looses all the formatting and shows the bare list(and autocomplete doesn't seem to work in iphone) :( - i want result to look like - http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/lists/docs-lists.html#/test/docs/lists/lists-search.html using firebug, i extract the input box from above example and I am almost there using Ajax...

Comment: jQuery UI autocomplete works just fine in iOS with jQuery Mobile—I have it deployed in a production app right now—but by default it does just that: it provides autocomplete suggestions in a field. What you're after is a way of filtering an in-page list, so I would just look to re-create the code used in that page.

Answer (score 0):

In case you're still interested but I doubt you are

```
$("#textbox-filter").autocomplete({
                minLength: 2,
                source: '/AutoComplete/XYZ',
                search: function (event, ui) {
                    $("ul#listview li.ac").remove();
                },
                open: function (event, ui) {
                    $("ul#listview").listview('refresh');
                }
            })
            .data("autocomplete")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
                $('<li class="ac"><a href="#one">' + item.value + '</a></li>').appendTo("ul#listview");
                return null;
            };
```